# How @Tested internally creates object for singleton class?

Tags: jmockit

@Tested internally instantiates the class object.  But in case of singleton class how @Tested internally creates instance because for singleton private constructor is there.

Comment: JMockit comes with the `Deencapsulated` class, allowing you to invoke private methods and constructors. I would expect something similar is done here.

Answer (score 0):

Private constructors (or fields, methods, etc.) can always be executed/accessed through Reflection.

When `@Tested` is used, an instance gets created regardless of the constructor's accessibility. This is described in the [API documentation](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Tested.html):

> if there are multiple satisfiable constructors then the one with the most parameters and the widest accessibility (ie, first public, then protected, then package-private, and finally private) is chosen.